# WMI Provider Host high CPU usage due to DellDataVault

Tags: windows, windows-10, cpu

Several months ago, when I upgraded to Win10, WMI Provider Host started using about 70% of my CPU! After the anniversary update it got even worse. Now it's 85% of my CPU!

I can't really disable it, because it restarts immediately.  If I use Piriform Speccy, it stops just fine, however I can't start any programs while it's suspended.

I have a bunch of WMI activity errors in event viewer, their client ID's are linked to DellDataVault.

Specs:
Alienware M18X, Intel Core i7-2820QM, 16 gb ram, Windows 10 Home(latest).

Thanks for any help! I will answer your questions as soon as I can!

Comment: You should remove the software connected to, Dell Data Vault, which of course is `Dell SupportAssist`.  You can always install it again if you actually need it.  If you have never needed it in all the years you had your laptop, its safe, to remove it given your dell support window is ended ways

Comment: http://forum.sysinternals.com/profsvc-using-significant-cpu-wbemcoredll_topic30521_post143023.html#143023 (for Win10, use the Win10 WTP from Win10 SDK: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)